# where can i find "ActiveDirectory" reference to add in my project?

Tags: c#, reference, active-directory, namespaces

i have an issue using

```
System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory
```

namespace in my project. visual studio gives me an error the :

```
The type or namespace name 'ActiveDirectory' does not exist in the namespace 'System.DirectoryServices'
```

i need to add reference to solve this problem.
thanks for any help

Comment: You add the reference to your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand your project in the Solution Explorer, then Right Click on 'References' > 'Add Reference' and look for 'DirectoryServices' under 'Assemblies'.

Once added you should probably use the using statement to reference active directories at the top of your page.

```
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory
```

Comment: man thank you. god bless you

Comment: @KhaledRakhisi You're welcome. Please mark this as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: This only works if your Solution is using the .NET Framework.  This does not work if your Solution is .NET Core.